# Error trying to run: Shockwave COM onbject on a test machine

Tags: vb.net, axshockwaveflash

I have a problem:
I have added the shockwave com object into my vb.net project and it works fine.
My development machine is a 64bit Windows 7

However on a test machine which is also windows 7 and has shockwave installed, I get the following error:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred creating the form.
See Exception.InnerException for details.
The error is: Could not load file or assembly 'AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects,    Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.
   at SENpic.Video_Player.InitializeComponent()
   at SENpic.Video_Player..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SENpic.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T Instance)
   at SENpic.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_Video_Player()
   at SENpic.frmStart.SensorySensitivityNationalAutisticSocietyToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

As far as I can see it should just work, any ideas?

Regards
Graham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted it. I hadn't noticed that in my build area two DDL files appeared:

```
AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll
Interop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll
```

I copied these into the folder with my EXE and the programme now played the files.